# Recursive formula for partial fraction decomposition of a specific kind of fractions

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

I need to make a partial fraction decomposition of the following fraction :

$$  \frac{1}{(x-a)^2(x-b)^2(x-c)^2(x-d)^2(x-e)} $$

The problem is that Wolfram doesn't give any answer : http://wolfr.am/49l6Tjzy

Could someone help me please ?

More precisly I am trying to find a recursive formula for this kind of fractions :

$$ \frac{1}{(x-a)^2(x-b)^2(x-c)^2(x-d)^2(x-e)^2(x-f)} $$

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Once you have done $\frac 1{(x-a)(x-b)^2}$ and $\frac 1{(x-a)^2(x-b)^2}$ Then $\frac 1{(x-a)(x-b)^2(x-c)^2}=\frac 1{(x-c)^2}\frac 1{(x-a)(x-b)^2}$ can be solved by writing the second fraction in partial fractions, then multiplying through - at each stage you are doing something you already know. And this can be done as an induction.

Comment: I think you can also do it like this too but it might be too bashy and tedious. Denote the fraction as $I$ and consider the set $A=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$

$$I=\frac{x-f}{\displaystyle\prod_{i\in A}(x-i)^2}=\sum_{i\in A}\frac{i_1x+i_2}{(x+i)^2}$$

Comment: Now, use partial fractions by taking $x\in A$ and solving for the unknown constants. Although I'm not sure whether this will be much help since there are way too many unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Let:
$$ h(a_1,\ldots,a_n;x)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x-a_j)^{-1}.\tag{1}$$
By the residue theorem:
$$ h(a_1,\ldots,a_n; x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\operatorname{Res}(h,x=a_j)}{x-a_j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-a_j)\prod_{k\neq j}(a_k-a_j)}\tag{2}$$
and now we just need to multiply $h(a_1,\ldots,a_{n};x)$ and $h(a_1,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1};x)$:
$$h(a_1,\ldots,a_{n};x)\cdot h(a_1,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1};x)=\textstyle{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-a_j)\prod_{k\neq j}(a_k-a_j)}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-a_j)\prod_{k\neq j}(a_k-a_j)}+\frac{1}{(x-a_{n+1})\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a_j-a_{n+1})}\right)}\tag{3}$$
and by setting $A_j=\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\neq j}}^{n}(a_k-a_j)$ and $A_{n+1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a_k-a_{n+1})$ we just need to exploit:
$$\frac{1}{(x-a_{j_1})A_{j_1}}\cdot \frac{1}{(x-a_{j_2})A_{j_2}}=\frac{1}{(a_{j_1}-a_{j_2})A_{j_1}A_{j_2}}\left(\frac{1}{x-a_{j_1}}-\frac{1}{x-a_{j_2}}\right)\tag{4}$$
to find the full partial fraction decomposition of $(3)$.